# Wants to get list of all junior doctors working under senior doctor and vice versa?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

here is my table DoctorInfo

```
|doctorId | firstname | seniorDoctorId |
   34         ABC          0
   35         XYZ          34
   36         bsd          34
   37         dfdf         35
   38         dffdg        0
```

1.if i put doctorId as 34 and seniorDoctorId as 0 then i want output as

```
 |doctorId | firstname | seniorDoctorId |
   34         ABC           0
   35         XYZ          34
   36         bsd          34
   37         dfdf         35
```

2.if i put doctorId as 35 and seniorDoctorId as 34 then i want output as

```
|doctorId | firstname | seniorDoctorId |
    35         XYZ          34
    37         dfdf         35
```

this is my query :

```
select 
   doctorId,
   firstname,   
   seniorDoctorId
from DoctorInfo as a
where a.doctorId in
         (
             select 
                b.seniorDoctorId 
             from 
                DoctorInfo b 
             where 
                b.seniorDoctorId=@doid
         ) 
 or a.seniorDoctorId in
         (
             select 
                c.doctorId 
             from 
                DoctorInfo c
         )
```

Comment: Glad to help. See my edit and learn how to format you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to navigate hierarchies is using a recursive CTE.  For example, to find all doctors that are junior to number 34, try:

```
; with  ServantList as
        (
        select  *
        from    @DoctorInfo
        where   doctorId = 34
        union all
        select  di.*
        from    ServantList sl
        join    @DoctorInfo di
        on      sl.doctorId = di.seniorDoctorId
        )
select  *
from    ServantList
```

[Example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62550/new)

Comment: :can we do same query without using CTE

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @DoctorInfo TABLE
                (
                    doctorId INT,
                    fistName VARCHAR(100),
                    seniorDoctorId INT
                )

INSERT INTO @DoctorInfo
VALUES
    (34,'ABC',0),
    (35,'XYZ',34),
    (36,'bsd',34),
    (37,'dfdf',35),
    (38,'dffdg',0)
```

The the query like this:

```
DECLARE @doctorId INT
SET @doctorId=35
;WITH CTE(doctorId,seniorDoctorId,fistName)
AS
(
    SELECT
        DoctorInfo.doctorId,
        DoctorInfo.seniorDoctorId,
        DoctorInfo.fistName
    FROM
        @DoctorInfo AS DoctorInfo
    WHERE
        DoctorInfo.doctorId=@doctorId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DoctorInfo.doctorId,
        DoctorInfo.seniorDoctorId,
        DoctorInfo.fistName
    FROM
        @DoctorInfo AS DoctorInfo
        JOIN CTE
            ON DoctorInfo.seniorDoctorId=CTE.doctorId
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
```

To get the desierd output you don't have to use the `seniorDoctorId` because they already have a parent child relation.

See example [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62560/example-of-cte-function)

Comment: This will get you the result you are showing in the output 2. If you what output 1 change the @doctorId to 34

Comment: Added a query output. See the link in the answer. I think it is correct

Comment: @Mayur: you can upvote an answer that's helpful, I'll +1 this one too :)

Comment: Thank :P. Now it was worth the effort :)