# Can we write the same query without using CTE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[Wants to get list of all junior doctors working under senior doctor and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462860/wants-to-get-list-of-all-junior-doctors-working-under-senior-doctor-and-vice-ver)

Comment: Can you explain why the CTE solution is no longer valid?

Comment: CTE crates the temprory resultset i want to write it in sngle line query

Comment: @Mayur: **WHY!?!?!** If the CTE solution works - **WHY** do you need to use something else instead!?!? **IT WORKS!** - so use it and be happy and move on ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any magical one-line query that's going to be any more efficient than a recursive CTE - this is the problem they were designed to solve. If the CTE solution is slow then it's probably not the CTE's fault - you'll need to look at the query plan and see why it's slow... do you have proper indexes to support the query? Have you looked at the execution plan? Are there 8 billion rows in the table?